# Is there a way to programmatically restart a tmux session (or pane)?

Tags: tmux

I know I can easily restart a tmux pane interactively via `bind-key r respawn-pane -k`. But how can I do this programmatically? Say I have a session named "MY_SESSION" and I want to restart all its panes, what bash command should I run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this for windows:

```
tmux lsw -tMY_SESSION: -F'#{window_id}'|while read i; do tmux respawn-window -kt$i; done
```

Or for panes:

```
tmux lsp -s -tMY_SESSION: -F'#{pane_id}'|while read i; do tmux respawn-pane -kt$i; done
```

Comment: Note that it's better to get the panes' PIDs (`#{pane_pid}`) and kill the processes directly before restarting the panes. Otherwise, some processes might not die when the panes are killed.